# Не импортирует модуль, почему?

Tags: python

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'services' from 'WorldTimeAPI'
(/home/eyex/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/WorldTimeAPI/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Нужны детали: что за модуль `WorldTimeAPI`, как вы его ставили, совместим ли он с `python 3.10`?

Comment: В том модуле [world-time-api](https://pypi.org/project/world-time-api/#description), который опубликован на PyPI, никакого подмодуля services и в самом деле не существует, а в его документации ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В том модуле world-time-api, который опубликован на PyPI, никакого подмодуля services и в самом деле не существует, а в его документации ошибка.